# Why are changes not synced to replica instances on Kubegres Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql, postgresql-replication

I have set up a Postgres on Kubernetes cluster with Kubegres with 3 instances - 1 master and 2 replicas. Now, I am facing the problem that the replication doesn't really work. What is synced, is when databased are newly created. What is not synced:

- creating tables
- Inserting/modifying data

I went through those steps: https://www.kubegres.io/doc/getting-started.html Did I miss sth.? I am also not sure if it is part of postgres itself or kubegres.

This is the log of one of the replicas:

```
2023-07-24 12:46:31.983 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2023-07-24 12:46:31.983 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-07-24 12:46:31.983 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-07-24 12:46:31.986 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-07-24 12:46:31.995 GMT [26] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-07-24 12:46:30 GMT
2023-07-24 12:46:32.071 GMT [26] LOG:  entering standby mode
2023-07-24 12:46:32.074 GMT [26] LOG:  redo starts at 0/E000028
2023-07-24 12:46:32.075 GMT [26] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/E000100
2023-07-24 12:46:32.075 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2023-07-24 12:46:32.079 GMT [30] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/F000000 on timeline 4
```

EDIT: I posted that question on stackoverflow before, but got the recommendation to post it at serverfault. I deleted the old posting since there were no helping responses.